# In JAVA, can we use predefined class name as a variable name?

Tags: java, class

An interviwer asked this question. I answered False. Am I correct?

Comment: can you give us more info?

Comment: This would be very easy to test for yourself.

Comment: Fire up a text editor and try it. Something like List list = new List();

Comment: `public class Foo { Foo Foo = new Foo(); }`. It compiles with no problem. Or: `String String = "String"; System.out.println(String);`. Again, it compiles with no problems.

Comment: I am not from Java background... thats why posted this..

Comment: Google magic my friend

Comment: You actually can, as long as it's not in java.lang and you haven't imported the class

Comment: @ArunKizhakkethil Does not coming from a Java background prevent you from testing your own proposition? If so, your problem is not unfamiliarity with Java, but lack of initiative.

Comment: You must do some research. You must try to compile this for yourself. We're not a free compiler service.

Comment: I am not working any programming languages... And even I donot know what is a predefined class is. Is "String" an predefined class?

Comment: Your last comment shows that you're not even trying to learn the language, you're not putting any effort at all in learning Java. But still, you're applying for a work or any other place where you will use Java. This is off topic for the site and you shall not pass this test until you study Java or the required elements/technologies for whatever you're applying-

Comment: +1. I find it an interesting problem. Think about it: `String Integer = ""; Integer max = Integer.MAX_VALUE;` will not compile! Food for thought for the language designers, in my opinion.

Comment: @Elist that doesn't compile because you have a variable called `Integer` and you're forgetting that `Integer max` should be `java.lang.Integer max`. OP's question is if you're allowed to declare variables with the name of Java predefined classes, and that works with no problems.

Comment: Of course it is `java.lang.Integer`, but once imported into the file, why not preserve it and consider it as duplicate (same question goes for fields and variables with same name) when the code declers a variable with the same name? Why not avoid the ambiguty? The answer to OP's question is obvius, and yet, I find it interesting.

Comment: Answering just true or false to this is not a good enough answer to a hiring manager. You should explain your answer. For example, you can do int List = 0 and List is a predefined class in the java language...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we can use predefined class name as variable. following code will work perfectly

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int BufferedOutputStream = 3; //BufferedOutputStream is predefined class
        System.out.println(BufferedOutputStream);
    }
}
```

it is also possible to use user defined class name as variable name. example

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Test2 Test2 = new Test2();
        System.out.println(Test2.a);
    }
}

public class Test2
{
    public int a = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> In Java, can we use predefined class name as a variable name?

The basic rule for naming in Java is that you cannot use a keyword as name of a class, name of a variable nor the name of a folder used for package. This is stated in [Java Specification Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9):

> **3.9. Keywords**
>
> 50 character sequences, formed from ASCII letters, **are reserved for use as keywords and cannot be used as identifiers** ([§3.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8))
>
> Keyword:
>
> ```
> abstract   continue   for          new         switch
> assert     default    if           package     synchronized
> boolean    do         goto         private     this
> break      double     implements   protected   throw
> byte       else       import       public      throws
> case       enum       instanceof   return      transient
> catch      extends    int          short       try
> char       final      interface    static      void
> class      finally    long         strictfp    volatile
> const      float      native       super       while
> ```

These are invalid names in Java world:

```
int boolean = 5; //invalid!
boolean goto = false; //invalid!
String default = "string"; //invalid!
com.foo.assert.MyClass myClass = new com.foo.assert.MyClass(); //invalid! Because of assert used as folder
```

But using any predefined class in Java won't cause such compiler error since Java predefined classes **are not** keywords:

```
String Integer = "foo";
System.out.println(Integer);
```

Output:

```
foo
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with keywords. `String s; String s;` will not compile just as well.

Comment: @Elist this has to do with keywords.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest that a predefined class name can be used as a variable name, but is lowercase.

like "Box box = new Box()".  Only "Box" can only be used as a class name.  "box" can be used as an object name.

"Box" is otherwise protected as class name.

Comment: *"Box" is otherwise protected as class name.* are you really sure of this? Have you tested it before posting it here as answer?

Comment: I think he meant it is his suggetion that it will be protected, which I tend to agree for class names imported in the same file.

Comment: @Elist is not protected. The only *protected* words in Java are keywords. Everything else can be used as variable name with no problem, but you take the risks of doing this.,

Comment: Not just keywords. Variable names cannot be duplicated in the same scope, as well as class names in the same package. The compiler will not allow this. Why not do the same in this case and avoid the ambiguty? Why get the coder into the trap?